# Shape Operators and Symmetric Linear Transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The exercise (from Sakai) is:

> Let $f: E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and let $M_f := \{p = (x, f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^n\,;\,x \in E\}$ be the graph of $f$ considered as a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, if $Df(x) = 0$ at $x \in E, \partial_n$ is a unit normal vector to $M_f$ at $x$. The second fundamental form of $M_f$ at $x$ is given by $\langle S (\partial_i , \partial_j), \partial_n \rangle = \partial_i \partial_j f$. Using this fact, let $p$ be a point in a Riemannian manifold $M$, $u \in U_p M$, and $A$ a symmetric linear transformation of $u^{\perp} := \{v \in T_p M \,;\,\langle u, v \rangle = 0\}$. Show that there exists a hypersurface $N$ of $M$ around $p$ with unit normal $u$ at $p$ such that the shape operator $A_u$ is equal to the given $A$.

My thought is to let $\text{dim}M=m$ and let $\tilde{M}$ be a submanifold of dimension $m-1$ containing $p$. Then there exists (I hope) $f \in C^{\infty}(\tilde{M})$ with $Df(p)=0$, so $N$ would be the graph of $f$ considered as a hypersurface. If that works, how do I go about showing that $A=A_u$? Is it sufficient to show that $\langle A_u v, w\rangle = \langle A(v,w),u \rangle = v_i v_j \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \xi^i \partial \xi^j}(p)$ for some $v,w \in u^{\perp}$ and coordinates $(\xi^i)$ of $M$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @ JoeDub:  Nice question, +1; ***BUT*** since $f:E \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, shouldn't $M_f = \{p = (x, f(x)) \in \Bbb R^{n + 1}; x \in E \}$? i.e., $x \in E$, $f(x) \in \Bbb R \Rightarrow (x, f(x)) \in \Bbb R^{n + 1}$!  My take on it, in any event.  Furthermore, did you mean to write $Df(x) = 0$ at $x \in E$ instead of $x \in D$?  Just wanted to clear a few things up before more fully engaging my math engine on this most interesting question!

Comment: Whoops, you're right on both counts! I've edited the original question. Thank you.

Comment: @ JoeDub:  no problem; as I said, nice question!